# How do you set an attribute value that is a JSON literal within a DOM

Tags: javascript, json, dom

I am trying to set the value of a key value in a JSON literal that is contained with a  tag,  for example, in the snippet below the data-info is the JSON literal.

```html
<video
  id="myPlayer_1"
  width="90%"
  poster="videos/posters/NoVideoPoster.png"
  data-info="{"start_time": "71522", "end_time":"71622", next_video:"0"}">
</video>
```

Now I can read the attribute using the following code:

```js
var ar = JSON.parse(videoElement.getAttribute("data-info"))
console.log("next video" + ar.next-_video);
```

but setting it is proving difficult, for example:

```js
videoElement.setAttribute("data-info.next_video", "1");
```

produces:

```html
<video
  id="myPlayer_1"
  width="90%"
  poster="videos/posters/NoVideoPoster.png"
  data-info="{"start_time": "71522", "end_time":"71622",next_video: "0"}"
  data-info.next_video = "1">
</video>
```

Which is obviously not correct.   Can anyone help?

Comment: You should take a look at [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)

Comment: It seems odd that two of the properties in your JSON use `_`, but one of them uses `-` instead.

Comment: I was having trouble copying it from the Brave debugging window so had to reproduce it and made the error - fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the *whole* attribute. To the DOM, remember, it's just a string.

So for instance, after having read and parsed it:

```
var ar = JSON.parse(videoElement.getAttribute("data-info"))
```

you can update it and set it again by converting back to JSON (a string):

```
ar["next-video"] = 1;
videoElement.setAttribute("data-info", JSON.stringify(ar));
```

---

If you're in control of the element and you need to update just parts of that information, you might consider separate `data-*` attributes rather than a single one with JSON in it. For instance:

```html
<video
    id="myPlayer_1"
    width="90%"
    poster="videos/posters/NoVideoPoster.png"
    data-start-time=71522
    data-end-time=71622
    data-next-video=0
></video>
```

Then updating the "next video" is:

```
videoElement.dataset.nextVideo = "1";
```

Note how `dataset` converts `data-next-video` to `nextVideo`. See the details [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
videoElement.setAttribute("data-info.next_video", "1");
```

you should do like this

```
var ar = JSON.parse(videoElement.getAttribute("data-info"))
ar.next_video = "1";
videoElement.setAttribute("data-info", JSON.stringify(ar));
```